# React Native - SyntaxError: Invalid RegExp: Parenthesized expression not closed when typing "(" on Input

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, expo

I am having a frustrating error on my react native app.

I have a component that has a TextInput, that is used to search content through an API. Now all has been working perfectly fine until one of our customers searched the following

"**14-12(**" which immediately crashes when entering the "("

The error that I am getting on the console is the following:

**SyntaxError: Invalid RegExp: Parenthesized expression not closed**

This is the code that handles the search:

```
 const [searchTerm, setSearchTerm] = useState("");




  //============================================================
  //Delay on call search
  //============================================================
  useEffect(() => {
    const delayDebounceFn = setTimeout(() => {
      (async () => {
        await handleSearch(searchTerm);
      })();
    }, 500);

    return () => clearTimeout(delayDebounceFn);
  }, [searchTerm]);


  //============================================================
  //Handle Search
  //============================================================
  const handleSearch = async (searchTerm) => {
    const headerOption = {
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
        Authorization: `Bearer ${user.token}`,
      },
    };

    setIsSearchLoading(true);

    axiosInstance
      .post(
        `/rest/V2/search`,
        { book_id: bookSku, search_term: searchTerm.toString() },
        headerOption
      )
      .then((response) => {
        // console.log(response);
        if (response.data.length > 0) {
          setSearchResults(response.data[1]);
        }
        setIsSearchLoading(false);
      })

      .catch((error) => {
        setIsSearchLoading(false);
        console.log(
          "Error fetching the search from the server SectionScreen",
          error
        );
      });
  };


    <TextInput
       autoFocus={true}
       style={styles.searchInput}
       placeholder="Enter Search Term"
       onChangeText={(value) => setSearchTerm(value.toString())}
       value={searchTerm}
       returnKeyType="done"
      />
```

Anyone has any idea what might the issue? How can I make the input accept the ( ??

Thank you!

React Native: "0.71.8"

"react": "18.2.0"

"expo": "^48.0.0"

Comment: The error seems pretty obvious: the code expects the value in the input to be a valid regular expression, so when it isn't, the code fails. To "fix" it you will have to decide what the application should do, and that's up to you.

Comment: OK maybe I asked the wrong question... How do I get this to work? Why is it that I can't have a ( on my input? How do I make it accept that?

Comment: Regular expression syntax is kind-of complicated; all sorts of things can make a string be invalid. Again, exactly what you should do depends on how you want your application to work. One possibility is that if there's a regular expression syntax error, your code could catch that and fall back to a plain string search. Whether that's a good idea for your situation, I can't say.

Comment: Yes that is what I need it to do. just be a string send whatever characters to the api as a string... I don't know how to do that, would you be able to help me on that please?